# Parse javascript code as response

Tags: javascript, node.js

After retrieving a GET request from some server I get as response this:

```
variable1 = ["something", ["a","b","c"], ["more stuff"]]
```

I need to extract the `variable1[1]` array `["a","b","c"]` to be used in my js code.

(I am using NodeJS for the request - it is a server side request to an external web service which I have no control over)

Comment: Cool. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Are you familiar with `JSON.parse` and `String.prototype.split`?

Comment: What? I don't understand...

Comment: I assume this is supposed to be JSON ... so if so, go read up on how to work with that.

Comment: i havent tried anything because other than regex i have no clue how to even look at this problem, it is not json.. will JSON.parse even look at this?

Comment: I'm lost - `I need to extract the variable[1] array ["a","b","c"] to be used in my js code.` so did `variable1[1]` not work then?

Comment: @Mike `JSON.parse` will work on the part after the `=`. You can use `split` to only get the section after the `=`.

Comment: hmm.. thats a good idea.. i should just find the first "=" and just JSON.parse the rest. Thanks alot!!

Comment: @Mikec `JSON.parse` will only work on a JSON string. Not a JS array.

Comment: `i should just find the first "="` - What `=`? I'm so confused, there seems to be more info in the comments then in the question, looking at the question I have no idea what the question is :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Arrays are valid JSON. Try running `JSON.parse('["something", ["a","b","c"], ["more stuff"]]')`

Comment: @MikeC you're correct, but you're still parsing a string. Not an array.

Comment: @evolutionxbox The point is that they have a string and they need to convert that to a value. Check the accepted answer if you're still not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your return value is a string containing the complete expression.

Assuming you have this in a string:

`'variable1 = ["something", ["a","b","c"], ["more stuff"]]'`

and you want to retrieve `variable1[1]` meaning: `["a","b","c"]`

You can split the string by `=` then parse it with `JSON.parse()` followed by querying it for the desired index `[1]` like below:

```js
var x = 'variable1 = ["something", ["a","b","c"], ["more stuff"]]';
var y = JSON.parse(x.split('=')[1])[1];

console.log(y);
```

> As you already had accepted the answer I will leave the below solution
>   in it but would recommend the above.

You can also create a new function and return the expression result, similar to this:

```
var x = 'variable1 = ["something", ["a","b","c"], ["more stuff"]]';

var y = new Function('return ' + x);
```

You then can return what you want similar to get `variable1[1]`

> **Warning**
>   `New Function()` presents possibly the same risks as `eval()` and specially if retrieving expressions in JSON strings from a third party service you have no control over could you end up executing Malicious code without knowing!

```js
var x = 'variable1 = ["something", ["a","b","c"], ["more stuff"]]';

console.log(new Function('return ' + x)()[1]);
```

Comment: You are awesome!! than you :))

Comment: @Mike Word of Warning though - If `New Function()` presents the same issues as `eval()` it might not be safe to use as you could end up executing malicious code without knowing.

Comment: @Fran That's why splitting on `=` and `JSON.parse`ing the expression would be better.

Comment: @MikeC Given `New Function` turned out to be risky you are right and I added the alternative as well now `JSON.parse(x.split('=')[1])[1];` - I also placed it as the recommended solution above the accepted one. I leave the `New Function` solution there too, simply because it was accepted originally.

Comment: @MikeC Yup, as intended,  it only returns `["a","b","c"]` what OP is looking for. - `I need to extract the variable1[1] array ["a","b","c"]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a safer way of getting the value of that expression, consider splitting the result on the first `=` then doing `JSON.parse` on the expression.

```js
const input = 'variable1 = ["something", ["a","b","c"], ["more stuff"]]';
const expression = input
  // Split the string on the equals sign
  .split('=')
  // Gather the pieces after the first one (just in case there's a "=" in the array)
  .slice(1)
  // Put it back together into a single string
  .join('');
  
// Convert the string to an actual array
const output = JSON.parse(expression);
console.log(output);
```

This method completely avoids the security issues with `Function`, `eval`, and related methods.